# States graph for the '3 jugs of water'

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm

Regarding the 3 jugs of water problem:

we have 3 water jugs that the capacity of first jug is 12 and capacity of second jug is 8 and capacity of third jug is 3.
the initial state is: (0,0,0)
the successor function is:

1. Add: completely fill a jag
2. Pour to another one: Pour the content of one jug two a second one (until the first is empty or second is completely full)
3. Empty is: empty a jar from all its content

The goal state is: (1,1,1)

---

i want to draw its state tree. i did it by myself but i'm not really sure that it is right or not?

```
         (0,0,0)
        /   |    \
       /    |     \
      /     |      \
(12,0,0) (0,8,0) (0,0,3)
```

the child node for(12,0,0) is: (12,0,0),(12,8,0),(12,8,3),(0,8,3),(0,0,3),(0,0,0),(9,8,3),(12,8,0),(4,8,3),(12,0,3),(12,5,3),(12,5,3),(12,8,0)

which (12,0,0),(0,0,0)==>because it is in root,(12,8,0)==> 
are fail node and we don't expand them.

i think if i expand (0,0,3), i will reach to my goal state:
the child for the node (0,0,3): (3,0,0),(0,3,0),(0,0,3),(1,1,1) (1,1,1) is the goal state am i right?

**Question:** Am I understanding it correctly? Are these the states and generated tree?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question is it?

Comment: @musefan: It is. It is the [Die-Hard Problem](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfQxZTtbCTg), which is solveable with A*, for example. It is a basic training for problems solving using reduction to graphs.

Comment: So what programming language does the OP want the answer in? This is more about algorithms that programming.

Comment: algorithms are perfectly fine in here. We don't only answer "How to split a string in C", answering algorithms, which can be later be translated to code in any PL is very programming related and is perfectly fine here.

Comment: hmmm... I thought we had a specific site for algorithms... seems not though

Comment: yes you're right it is not an programming question? i want to know am i expanding the node right. is the child node for (12,0,0) is (12,0,0),(12,8,0),(12,8,3),(0,8,3),(0,0,3),(0,0,0),(9,8,3),(12,8,0),(4,8,3),(12,0,3),(12,5,3),(12,5,3),(12,8,0)

Comment: amit say right, if we know concept then translate to any code is just like peace of cade!!!

Answer (score 3):

The graph is correct for the first step, however - you expand the siblings (12,0,0), (0,8,0) and (0,0,3) wrong. 

You should do a single step, not multiple in each iteration, and not try to do many steps.

Thus:

```
successors((12,0,0)) = { (12,0,3), (12,8,0), (0,0,0), (9,0,3), (4,8,0) }
successors((0,8,0)) = { (12,8,0), (0,8,3), (8,0,0), (0,5,3), (0,0,0) }
successors((0,0,3)) = { (12,0,3), (0,8,3), (3,0,0), (0,3,0), (0,0,0) }
```

(From each state, you can only do 1 allowed operation, not more - to get the successors/following states).

By keep expanding these, you will get eventually all possibilities.

---

FYI, this problem is sometimes known as [**The Die Hard Problem**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfQxZTtbCTg), and is a classic example of problem solving using reductions to graph algorithms by building the states [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) and running a pathfinding algorithm, such as [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) or [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Comment: Did you mean you could go from (12,0,0) to (12,0,3) in a single step? Technicly I think it's two steps.

Comment: @AlexanderChertov: It is a single step, given `(12,0,0)` - fill the jag with capacity `3` (the third one) completely with water, leaving you with `(12,0,3)`. (The standard problem assumes infinite source of water for refilling jugs completely, and you can completely fill each one of these.)

Comment: I would say re-filling is a separate step.

Comment: @AlexanderChertov: `(0,0,0)->(12,0,0)->(12,0,3)`, there is no actually refilling here. You fill jag of 12 (1st step) and then a jag of 3 (2nd step), totaling in 2 operations (=steps) overall. If you think some if this steps is not trivial as one step, please be specific which one it is. (Note, there are no preconditions on filling the jag of 3 from the lake, if you think this is the issue). Thus, the transfer from (12,0,0) (and not from the init state) to (12,0,3) is a single step.

Comment: you're right. Sorry, I wasn't attentive.

Comment: why is everyone writing "jag" instead of "jug"? `a` and `u` are not even close on the keyboard.

Comment: @st0le: Not a native english speaker, just repeating the same mistake I guess. Feel free to edit any language mistakes I make! (I clearly ask for it in my profile, and I really do appritiate it!)

Comment: @amit, hey me too, I just asked coz the OP and you wrote it correct first then began with the typo. Sorry about being the Grammar Nazi that i am.

Comment: @st0le: No need to sorry, everytime I get corrected my English improve a little bit, fine with me :)